# Difference between measurable and $\mu$-measurable (Baby Rudin)

Tags: measure-theory

I am currently on the last chapter of Baby Rudin (Lebesgue Theory). Rudin only seems to (I could be wrong here) define $\mu$-measurability (of a set) on page 305, and I was wondering if this is synonymous with (a set) being measurable (on page 310). If not, can someone elucidate the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On page 305, Rudin is defining the concept of measurability with respect to a particular measure $\mu$. One can presume that many such measures exist, and each will have its own concept of measurability. So calling a set "measurable" must be qualified by the particular measure referenced.

On page 310, Rudin is now speaking within the confines of a particular measure space, which comes with a distinguished measure. Thus there is no longer a need to specify the measure providing the concept of measurability, since all other measures have been exiled from the theory. (They can still come in under tourist visas, but their stuff has to be clearly labelled, because anything unlabeled automatically belongs to *the one true measure* of this measure space).